# JavaScript window resize event is slow. How to optimize window resize event

Tags: javascript

When I click on the Maximize button of the browser window, a function I wrote that will execute when the window is resized, does not work properly I think because JavaScript window resize event is running slow. It worked when I used the mouse to resize the window. Also, when I tried to change between portrait mobile to landscape mobile it is also slow.

Faced a problem with using with `window.addEventListener('resize', aFunction)`, page gets slow. These events are generated multiple times per second, and if the event handler takes too much time, the browser won’t catch with redrawing the page.

```js
function aFuntion() {
  let div1 = document.querySelector('.div1');
  let div2 = document.querySelector('.div2');
  let diff = div1.clientHeight - div2.clientHeight;
  div2.style.top = diff + 'px';
};

// Call the function.
// This worked!
aFuntion();

// Call the function when users resize the window.
// This worked!
window.addEventListener('resize', aFuntion);

// Users click on the Maximize button of the window.
// The function does not work properly!

// Portrait mobile to Landscape mobile.
// The function does not work properly!
```

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .div2 {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What operating system? Does this happen with all browsers?

Comment: I tried it on the Google Chrome browser and Firefox browser. Both are not working. I wonder does the window resize event keeps track of the action of clicking on the Maximize button of the browser window or it only keeps track of the resize using the mouse.

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome in Mac OS, it worked fine. I put `console.log("resized");` in the function, and I got the log message when I clicked on the maximize button.

Comment: My function is included changing the top position for an element and it is not just console.log() as you test. Can you try to add a top position to the function you are testing? An element that I am trying to add top position is an image. I also call clientHeight.

Comment: Why does it matter what the function does? You said the problem is that it isn't being called.

Comment: If it matters, you should put the actual code into the question so we can try it.

Comment: Okay. I solved my own problem. Somehow transition: all 0.5s ease; make the resize not working. I removed the transition: all 0.5s ease;  and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I removed transition: all 0.5s ease; and it worked for a while now it is not working again.

So, I know now it is because of window.addEventListener('resize', function) is running slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var timeout = false;
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(aFuntion, 200);
});
```

Read: https://bencentra.com/code/2015/02/27/optimizing-window-resize.html

Answer (score -1):

try with `document.addEventListener('resize', aFuntion);`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23032618)

Comment: that's not a critique, it's a real solution i adopted myself and it worked many times in lots of situations

Comment: This is not working for my case. I tried and it is not working.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Why do you think this isn't an answer? Whether or not it's correct, it's a sincere attempt to provide a solution.